# How to covert a Dataframe to a Dataset,having a object reference of the parent class as a composition inside another class?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-encoders

I am trying to convert a `Dataframe` to a `Dataset`, and the java classes structure is as follows:

class A:

```java
public class A {

    private int a;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

class B:

```java
public class B extends A {

    private int b;

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and class C

```java
public class C {

    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

and the data in the dataframe is as follows :

```
+-----+
|  a  |
+-----+
|[1,2]|
+-----+
```

When I am trying to apply Encoders.bean[C](classOf[C]) to the dataframe. The object reference `A` which is a instance of `B` in class `C` is not returning true when I am checking for .isInstanceOf[B], I am getting it as false. The output of Dataset is as follows:

```
+-----+
|  a  |
+-----+
|[1,2]|
+-----+
```

How do we get all the fields of A and B under the C object while iterating over it in foreach?

Code :-

```
object TestApp extends App {

  implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Test-App")
    .config("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", value = false)
    .master("local[1]")
    .getOrCreate()


  var schema = new StructType().
    add("a", new ArrayType(new StructType().add("a", IntegerType, true).add("b", IntegerType, true), true))


  var dd = sparkSession.read.schema(schema).json("Test.txt")

  var ff = dd.as(Encoders.bean[C](classOf[C]))
  ff.show(truncate = false)



  ff.foreach(f => {
    println(f.getA.get(0).isInstanceOf[A])//---true
    println(f.getA.get(0).isInstanceOf[B])//---false
  })
```

Content of File : `{"a":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}`

Comment: Could you review your examples? They don't much sense to me currently

Comment: @SašaZejnilović Added the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

`Spark-catalyst` uses [google reflection](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/13.0-rc1) to get schema out of java beans.
Please take a look at the [JavaTypeInference.scala#inferDataType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L146). This class uses getters to collect the field name and the returnType of getters to compute the `SparkType`.

Since class `C` has getter named `getA()` with returnType as `A` and `A`, in turn, has getter as `getA()` with returnType as `int`,
Schema will be created as `struct<a:struct<a:int>>` where `struct<a:int>` is derived from the `getA` of class `A`.

The solution to this problem that I can think of is -

```java
// Modify your class C to have Real class reference rather its super type
public class C {

    private B a;

    public B getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(B a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Output-

```
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)

+------+
|a     |
+------+
|[1, 2]|
+------+
```

Comment: There are 10-15 classes which extends class A. If I follow this approach I will have to maintain that many variations of class C. I am looking to avoid that.

Comment: Why can't you create your static schema having all the fields of A's subclasses rather depending on the schema created by reflection.

Comment: Can you give a sample?

Comment: Can you tell me the usecase? Basically wanted to know the input and expected output.